# Functional Programming in Node.js - Wait for completion of function

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming

I am a beginner with Node.js. Syntactically I am happy with JavaScript having used it to build web UIs. I have tones of OOP experience in Java and C#, and I understand functional programming basics. However, once the complexity gets above a certain point I start to find it challenging.

I am building a Node module which incorporates some other modules I have written. They each work fine on their own, but I am trying to incorporate them together.

```
var miner = require("./miner"),
    dbpedia = require("./dbpedia");

exports.getEntities = function(uri, callback) {
    miner.extractEntities(uri, function (entities) {
        var final = [];

        entities.forEach(function (element, index) {
            var newEntity = {
                id : element.id,
                title : element.title,
                weight : element.weight,
                uri : ""
            };

            dbpedia.getEntities(element.title, function(entity) {
                if (entity.length > 0) {
                    newEntity.uri = entity[0].URI[0];
                }

                final.push(newEntity);
            });
        });

        callback(final);
    });
};
```

The question I have is how do I put this all together so that I can call `callback` once `final` is fully populated. I am sure it is something simple, but I am struggling to work it out. I suspect that I might have to reverse the order, but I don't see how to do it.

Comment: Use promises or `async.map`.

Comment: No, it's not simple. If you are familiar with web UI, you should be familiar with asynchronous callbacks (event listeners)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming dbpedia.getEntities is an asynchronous function, the problem is the forEach loop won't wait on each iteration for the function to complete.
Like SLaks said, the easiest route is to use a library such as async.
These libraries have asynchronous loops. async.eachSeries would replace the forEach, but as above the async.map saves you defining the final array.

```
var miner = require("./miner"),
dbpedia = require("./dbpedia"),
async = require("async");

exports.getEntities = function(uri, callback) {
  miner.extractEntities(uri, function (entities) {
    async.map(entities, function(entity, callback) {
      var newEntity = {
        id : entity.id,
        title : entity.title,
        weight : entity.weight,
        uri : ""
      };

      dbpedia.getEntities(element.title, function(entity) {
        if (entity.length > 0) {
          newEntity.uri = entity[0].URI[0];
        }

        callback(null, newEntity);
      });

    }, function(err, results) {
      callback(null, results);
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score -2):

You want to make your code synchronous , there are lot of libraries out there to achive this , one of the interesting way to do is [node-sync](https://github.com/ybogdanov/node-sync)